# php: not getting file what does header() do?

Tags: php, file, download

I am very new to PHP. I am trying to make  simple script which allows the users to download files from a webpage.

```
<?php
require_once('Connections/connection_psfriend.php'); ?>

$receivedfilerequest = addslashes($_REQUEST['filesource']);
$file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.'ps-friend'.'/' . $receivedfilerequest;

  if(file_exists( $file_path)){
echo 'The file exists';       
 $size = filesize($file_path);    
   echo $size; //Its working perfectly fine till here. 

exit;

}
```

But what do I do next so that this file is actually downloaded. I saw some tutorials and they use `header("Location: ".$file_path);` after this. But that's not working for me. What does this header function actually do, and what should be the code to actually download this file?

Comment: Post your question over or under your code, not as `code`.

Comment: What should be the complete code to download the file and what does header(string) do?

Comment: OK i will edit the code

Comment: Why not just read the [***manual***](http://php.net/header)?

Comment: `header()` sends an HTTP header to the browser.  In this case it is sending a Location: header which instructs the browser to load another location (in this case your file). [link](www.php.net) is your friend. Check the documentation for header  at [link](http://au1.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: To understand the `header()` function, you really need to understand a bit about the HTTP protocol. Take a minute to [learn a bit about http headers here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/http-headers-for-dummies/)

Comment: The problem with `header()` is that it must be sent before any output. If you already pushed some HTML to the client you can no longer use `header()`. Headers to work must be sent first. If thats a problem to you, start your code with `ob_start()`, it will allow you to use `header()` anywhere.

Comment: To add to `Havenard's` comment, a `white space` before PHP will also trigger a `headers already sent` error message, so be careful as it can ruin a hard day's work ;-)

Comment: I will read more about headers and get whats wrong. Thnks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP's readfile (http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to force a file download, if that's what you are trying to do. There is an example on that page shows you how to download an image. 
The PHP header function sends a raw HTTP header to the client. The location header is usually used to redirect the client to a new page in PHP.

Comment: `readfile()` doesn't actually force the file to download. It just outputs the contents of the file. Forcing a download requires some content-type and content-disposition headers.

Comment: Yes, the example uses readfile and outputting headers to download a file.

Answer (score 1):

please refer this URL, it is used to download file

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php